# Getting server address and application name

Tags: java, servlets, jmx

Environment: NetBeans 6.9.1, GlassFish 3.1

I have a Java Web Application. How to get the server address and the application name dynamically? The '2in1' solution would be the best for me: `http://localhost:8080/AppName/`.

Is there a practical way to get that information?

Let's say the value of `AppName` will be fixed, so I only need the host address. Is it possible to retrieve it via JMX? Any other ways?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `HttpServletRequest` object will give you what you need:

- `HttpServletRequest#getLocalAddr()`: The server's IP address as a string
- `HttpServletRequest#getLocalName()`: The name of the server receiving the request
- `HttpServletRequest#getServerName()`: The name of the server that the request was sent to
- `HtppServletRequest#getLocalPort()`: The port the server received the request on
- `HttpServletRequest#getServerPort()`: The port the request was sent to
- `HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`: The part of the path that identifies the application

Comment: @Ging3r No. It is not. Perhaps you should heed your own advice about paying attention and read the appropriate documentation?

Comment: What does that pound sign in method name mean? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @ScottChu - I honestly cannot remember where I copied the above from 5 years ago. I agree that the "HttpServletRequest#" prefix is unusual and unnecessary.

Comment: ClassName#MethodName is a notation used in JavaDoc, for example within @see tag.

Answer (score 3):

Inside a servlet you can get it like this

```
public static String getUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getRequestURL().toString();
}
```

Comment: That gives the full request url, and not just the context path.