# How to get the client's browser ip from the request in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I know it is quite easy to get the client's IP and server IP from the httprequest in java. Is it possible to get the browser IP of the client at any means.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'browser IP of the client` if not the client's IP?

Comment: What is the difference between client IP and browser IP of the client? They should be the same.

Comment: client IP is the system's IP from which the req is made and the browser IP means the web connectivity IP through the req is made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand correctly

**You can get client IP with method**

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
String userIpAddress = httpRequest.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
```

Full quote:
[How to determine by what IP Address my website has been accessed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107739/how-to-determine-by-what-ip-address-my-website-has-been-accessed)

**Getting the server IP from request**:

```
HttpServletRequest.getLocalAddr();
```

Full quote: [Getting server address and application name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645916/getting-server-address-and-application-name)

**And getting the server ips can be done so**:

```
Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
```

Full quote:
[Getting the IP address of the current machine using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/how-to-get-ip-address-of-our-own-system-using-java)