# Get Sub Domain Name from an url

Tags: java, subdomain, vaadin

i want to read Url from web Browser (Vaadin 7)
my Server support sub domain , Url format : subdomain.applicationName.com
example : private.myapp.com  , public.myapp.com

i use the method  Page.getCurrent().getLocation() to read Url from Web browser but the returned value is

http://32.186.55.179/myapp  ==> i dont know why server return Ip adreess instead the domain Name

i want a way to read the value of sub domain entered in the Url

example : Url browser http://private.myapp.com  => result =private.myapp

Comment: In the example you provided you can do something like: `System.out.println(myUrl.substring(0,hello.lastIndexOf(".")));` which gives you: `http://private.myapp`

Comment: thank you   Brunaldo for your response 
but my problem is how to get the url from browser adress bar to extract sub domain , when i invoke HttpServletRequest.getServerName() it always returns the ip instead of subDomaine Name (String)

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5648259/4535117

Comment: thank for your interest i tried all those methods but they return always the same results ip adress when the url contains a sub domain .

Comment: Have you tried doing a reverse lookup? `String hostname = InetAddress.getByName(ip).getCanonicalHostName();`